# creating front end image uploader that uploads images as posts

Tags: posts, images, uploads

there is this website [lolhappens](http://www.lolhappens.com/) similar to 9gag. This is a website built over wordpress.

How i am sure of this? check this [link](http://www.lolhappens.com/wp-admin/) . Now to my best of knowledge this is a wordpress website where the images are shown as posts and their thumbnails(a fixed width and variable height) are shown of front page in a recent ones first order. Now here is my question:

How did they implement a front end [image uploader](http://www.lolhappens.com/upload/) that ultimately shows that images as a posts.And how can i achieve similar functionality . If there are more than one ways what would probably be the recommended. Is there a plugin that has such functionality out of the box?

Secondly is it also possible that the person who uploads the images sees a preview before finally clicking a button to  it to the website

Thirdly they have to add a minimum number of tags (predefined tags and users cant add their own) and a tick that says it is adult pic or not before they can submit it .

Comment: Plug-in recommendations are off topic per the [faq].

Comment: its just an addition to the original question. my main aim is to find how exactly it was implemented because i have little clue how to and i am trying to replicate the same thing into my website.

Answer (score 1):

Lol happens uses feathered images 
so you can upload a pic , use as feathered image 
you can use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/
to achieve that 
make a page called submit or something put the short code the plugin gaves you 
enable uploading feathered images and thats it
or you can go with hard coding
use this tut to make that http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/
good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to pair [Auto Post Thumbnail Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/) with front-end image uploader. This plugins creates a post, sets featured image and even can insert image in post, whenever any image is uploaded from wordpress interface.